# Deployment with SharePoint 2010

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010

What's the best practice of deploying structure/content in SharePoint 2010 from Test environment to Production? Provided that I don't want to overwrite existing content (specially list content) on production environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to deploy via Event Receivers and write code to evolve existing list structures and extend static content.
There is no easy tricks though.  List definitions are only helpful during initial roll out and list instance project items will overwrite by default, so be extremely careful.